# How can i stream a video from electron?

Tags: video-streaming, electron, record

I need electron application (win) to capture a video and stream it to me or send it to server.

Any example? I dont really have an understanding of how to do that.

Comment: You would need to use webrtc. https://webrtc.org/start/

Comment: What's the end goal? Are you looking to live stream that video feed to N people? If so, is that N number of people bigger than ~10?

Comment: number of ppl watching stream is 1-2. I need to help users online and see what are they doing. Streaming is needed on demand only